# PHP - String to int

Tags: php, casting

I have to generate unique ID depending on time, counter and random prepended value from 1 to 10. The way I generate it:

```
$time = (int)(time()+$i);
$time = $time.(rand(1,9));
//At this step we have strings looking like this:
"13480835672" //This is time in first iteration
"13480835672" //This is time in second iteration
//But if I convert it to int 
$time = (int)$time;
2147483647 //This is time converted in first iteration
2147483647 //This is time converted in second iteration
```

As you can see above times are same. All of them. What Am I missing here?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647#2147483647_in_computing

Comment: If you need larger numbers, you might want to have a look at BCMath http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Comment: @Mark it's cumbersome to use external libraries for things like this. GMP and BCMath are used for large number arithmetics and algebra, he doesn't seem to need that. A large float number will do or keeping it as a string.

Comment: It still depends, what he wants to do with this id. This is why I didn't post it as an answer, but as a comment. From my current point of view, the uniqid (plus a host-specific value etc) or a MD5 value of whatever would be best solution, but I don't want to jump to a conclusion without further information. ;)

Comment: @Mark I'm using MongoDB for database and I need to sort data. It has to be number. I cannot MD5 it for example and use it as string. That was my attempt. How would you do it?

Comment: It's hard to give a generic answer to that. Most probably, I'd leave the generation of the id up to the MongoDB (just don't provide an _id when inserting data, MongoDB will generate the ID by itself, see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs). For sorting, I'd just include the date field and let the DB do the sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2147483647 is the maximum (signed) integer number your operating system / php binary can work with.

2147483647*2 = 2^32 which means your operating system / php binary is working 32 bits.

In the above explanation I'm multiplying by two because the integers used by php are signed which means they span both on the negative and the positive axis of integer numbers.

Using a float value such as one returned by `microtime(TRUE)` allows you to work with much bigger numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) to get the exact time when the function occured.

You should also use [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) to get a proper random return.